# adding prices per date javascript/jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm hours busy with getting data from mysql and put in the jquery datepicker.
The php side is good. I tested it with get method and it works. So I struggle with the JS/Jquery side. JS doesn't see the variable myText. But I created one above.

```
function addCustomInformation() {

  $("#DatePicker td").filter(function() {
    var date = $(this).text();
    return /\d/.test(date);
  }).find("a, span").html(function(i, html) {
    var myText;
    var day = $(this).text();
    var month = $(".ui-datepicker-month").text();
    var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year").text();
    var date = day + " " + month + " " + year;

    $.ajax({
        url : "../../../func.php",
        type: "GET",
        data : {check_datum: date, ItemID: <?= $_GET["ItemID"] ?>},
        success: function(info)
        {
          myText = info;
          console.log(date + ", " + info);
        }
    });

    return html + "<br><small>$"+myText+"</small>";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `success` function is a callback, meaning it's run later/asynchronously. This means the `myText` variable will not be set when the return statement is run. To fix this, do:

```js
function addCustomInformation() {
  $("#DatePicker td").filter(function() {
    var date = $(this).text();
    return /\d/.test(date);
  }).find("a, span").html(function(i, html) {
    var $el = $(this);
    var day = $el.text();
    var month = $(".ui-datepicker-month").text();
    var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year").text();
    var date = day + " " + month + " " + year;

    $.ajax({
        url : "../../../func.php",
        type: "GET",
        data : {check_datum: date, ItemID: <?= $_GET["ItemID"] ?>},
        success: function(info) {
          console.log(date + ", " + info);
          $el.html(html + "<br><small>$" + info + "</small>");
        }
    });

    return html;
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. There's only one problem now. The results are loading very slow from the database. How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: That sounds like it would be an issue with your database setup/query, or with your php. It might be worth checking which of those is causing it to be slow. It's quite unlikely to be your JavaScript code though 

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax is an asynchronous function call, so the value for myText won't be set when your return statement executes.  You will need to update your html from within the success function.

Comment: Returning inside the success function will merely exit the `success` function rather than modify the result of the `.html` function, which has already returned by that point.